# Can't run Pybrain tutorial

Tags: python, python-2.7, pybrain

I'm trying to run one of these [tutorials](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/tree/master/docs/tutorials) and this is what I get:

```
$ python rl.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rl.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes import Maze, MDPMazeTask
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/rl/environments/mazes/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tasks.__init__ import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/rl/environments/mazes/tasks/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tiger import TigerTask
ImportError: No module named tiger
```

It installed successfully, not sure why it can't load it's own modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change file: `pybrain/pybrain/rl/environments/mazes/tasks/__init__.py` as:

```
from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tiger import TigerTask
```

to:

```
from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tasks.tiger import TigerTask
```

Comment: And I need to install it again? (to site-packages?)

Comment: You can simply go to your `site-packages` folder and edit the python files, then start a new `python` process, after you `import` the library, you will be using your edited version.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as suggested [here](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/issues/123), you should change the whole pybrain/pybrain/rl/environments/mazes/tasks/**init**.py as follows:

```
from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tasks.tiger import TigerTask
from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tasks.maze import TrivialMaze, MazeTask
from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tasks.cheesemaze import CheeseMaze
from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tasks.tmaze import TMaze
from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tasks.maze4x3 import FourByThreeMaze
from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tasks.maze89state import EightyNineStateMaze
from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tasks.shuttle import ShuttleDocking
from pybrain.rl.environments.mazes.tasks.mdp import MDPMazeTask
```

check `pybrain.rl.environments.__file__` to get the path to the file. This solved the importing problem for me.